# Nutrients in translucent bottles/boxes

Tags: organic-chemistry, food-chemistry, light

Nutrients e.g vitamin C, calcium etc are sensitive to light and that is the reason that major companies have juices and milks in boxes and opaque packages.
But there are some companies that the recent years use a transparent package/bottle (plastic or glass).
Does glass or plastic offer any kind of protection to the contents? What's the point of buying e.g. an orange juice in a transparent plastic bottle if the light is diminishing the vitamin C while in storage?

Comment: It's not like you put it direct sunlight, I hope? Otherwise I don't see a big deal.

Comment: I don't think that calcium is sensitive to light.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: in the grocery stores, super markets, convenience stores the light is always on

Comment: @Mithoron:do you think that during transport there is precautions to avoid sunlight? I have seen from time to time freeges in convenience stores that are exposed to light

Answer (score 1):

Ascorbic acid absorbs mainly below 300 nm, and when inside a building light at shorter wavelengths than 300 nm will be absorbed first by window glass and also a little by the packaging. Artificial lighting has little or no uv content, so you would be okay inside. If you keep the juice outside in sunshine it will be much more liable to under go some photochemistry as only the packaging will absorb and its much brighter. I suppose most folk will keep the juice is a cupboard or fridge anyway so it seems to be ok to use transparent packaging.

Comment: But I am pretty sure during transportation, there are no extra precautions to avoid sunlight or light. So I don't understand why companies use translucent packaging

Comment: So basically if artificial light has little uv content then having the item stored in a lit storage is ok?

Comment: Yes, provided that there is no visible light induced change to whatever else is in the bottles.

Comment: What about when consuming the content (juice, milk) in a glass outdoors where there's sunlight?